# Permutations are group homomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that $sgn (f(g))=sgn(f)sgn(g)$, where f and g are permutations?

I can only see in my notes that the proof somehow leads to the fact that the ring of polynomials has no divisors of 0 in it.

Answer (score 1):

The sign of a permutation is usually defined as $(-1)^n$ where $n$ is any number of transpositions needed to write down the permutation (this is well-defined mod $2$). If $f = \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_m$ and $g = \tau_1 \cdots \tau_n$ are decomposed into transpositions then the sign of $fg = \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_m \tau_1 \cdots \tau_n$ is $(-1)^{m+n}$, which is the product of the signs of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how $sgn(f)$ is usually defined, but my abstract algebra book defines it as $sgn(f) =$ det $P_{f}$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix corresponding to the permutation $f$. But then since $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ by rules of determinants, then $sgn(f)sgn(g)=\det P_{f}\det P_{g}=\det(P_{f} P_{g})$.
If you can prove that $P_{f} P_{g}= P_{f(g)}$, you're done, since this implies that  $sgn(f)sgn(g)=\det  P_{f(g)} = sgn(f(g))$.